# Writing to File in C# with/without relative paths

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

I am currently trying to get user input from commandline `OutputPath`

```
 using (outfile = new StreamWriter(OutputPath))
 {
     outfile.Write(result);
 }
```

This writes to absolute path if given or writes the file under c:\windows\system32

How can I make it either absolute path or depending on the current directory. Is there a way to get the current working directory from command line or is there a better API that can figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does know how to use relative paths based on the current directory.

If you're seeing files created in `C:\Windows\System32`, then probably that IS your current working directory.

A shortcut can set the working directory of the program it is launching.  Open/Save common file dialogs also mess with the current working directory.

If you launch an application without using a shortcut, it will inherit the current directory from the parent process.  `explorer.exe` usually has `C:\Windows\System32` as the working directory, which make it pretty common for applications launched by double-clicking an icon in Explorer.

Comment: you are right @Ben. I am using PowerShell and apparently the first path that powershell opens with is the one used. So if it was open as admin C:\windows\system32 will be used, otherwise it will be C:\users\myusername. why is that ? even though I am in another directory, it is the path that I started powershell in.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Path.IsPathRooted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted.aspx) to figure out whether the input is absolute or not, and [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) to get the current Directory. With this information you should be all set.

Comment: -1 for an answer that does nothing more than repeat information already given by Tigran.

Comment: @BenVoigt I did my own research, we ended up posting at roughly the same time. I don't why you'd downvote either.

Comment: At the time I voted, your answer said "one hour ago" and Tigran's comment said "2 hours ago".  I see that it was quite a bit closer, your answer came 7.5 minutes after his answer and 3 minutes after his comment.  But it still is just clutter to have multiple identical answers.  And the answer isn't even good, because it just duplicates (for considerable effort) what C# already does.  The problem is not finding the current directory, it's that the wrong director is current.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I confirm that both posted around the same time. Comment first before you downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) to get the current working directory on `OS`.

Comment: this means that I will need to check if the input is absolute and if not I can get current directory. I was wondering if there is an API I can use that can figure out both.

Comment: @Saher: you can use [Path.IsPathRooted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted.aspx) function to determine the *type* of the path passed, and based on that make your decision.